# <b>Fatal error</b>: Cannot use [] for reading

Tags: php, foreach

This code doesn't work > `<b>Fatal error</b>:  Cannot use [] for reading i`

```
  <select style=" width:200px" class="mydds"  name="myformdata[user][]">
```

this is what is sent.

```
myformdata[user][]  1
myformdata[user][]  2
myformdata[user][]  3

  foreach($form['user'][] as $val){
            echo ($val);
    }
```

what is the problem ?

Comment: Use `foreach ($form['user'])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a syntax error. The correct syntax is:

```
foreach($form['user'] as $val)
```

The `[]` syntax is used for appending data to an array. For example:

```
$form['user'][] = 'test';
```

The above will add a new string to the `$form['user']` array with the value of `test`.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($form['user'] as $val){
    echo ($val);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong. Others are suggesting `foreach()`, I will suggest a `for()` loop in addition:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($form['user']); $i++){
    echo ($form['user'][$i]);
}
```

Comment: It would be better to set the count in temp var :)

Comment: That's not necessary to demonstrate a for loop, but when optimizing (especially for large arrays), it is better to use a variable set to the result of the `count()`. This is because `count()` will get called each iteration, when it only needs to be called once.

Answer (score 0):

The result of the posted information (if I understand your explanation correctly) is:

```
$_REQUEST['myformdata']['user'] = array(1,2,3)
```

As the error states very clearly, you cannot use `[]` for reading.  When you use `foreach`, the code is trying to read the value before as.  It can't read with `[]`.  Instead try:

```
foreach ($_REQUEST['myformdata']['user'] as $val) { echo $val; }
```

Or if the information really is in `$form['user']` just use that and skip the `[]`